# Azure Table Storage and Null Property Values - Misleading Doc?

Tags: azure-table-storage

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model) states the following:

> The Table service does not persist null values for properties. **When querying entities, the above property types are all non-nullable**. When writing entities, the above property types are all nullable, and any property with a null value is handled as if the payload did not contain that property.

I bolded the text of interest to me.

Upon first glance, it seemed to me to state that **typed entity properties** will never be `null` after reading an entity from a row. This of course is untrue, verified by testing.

I had obviously misread the documentation. This documentation is referring specifically to the behavior of the REST response, so what's really happening is that the REST response simply omits properties for which it doesn't have a value stored. Thus by not persisting any `null` values, any properties in the REST results are guaranteed to be non-null, and those that would have been `null` are simply non-existent in the response (as long as an entity with null properties is replaced, rather than merged, when written).

Therefore, missing properties in the REST response being mapped to `ITableEntity` implementations MUST be inferred to be `null`.

Furthermore, to ensure that `null` values are actually "persisted", an entity must be replaced rather than merged.

Is my analysis of this correct?

If yes, then shouldn't the documentation be updated to make this clearer? It seems a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation means that a `null` value property won't be persisted in Azure Storage Table **service**, which has nothing to do with the implementation of the **client** library. Note that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model) is a **REST API documentation** rather than **client library documentation**. In current implementation of the client library, the missing properties in `ITableEntity` are kept as `null` when de-serializing the query response from Azure Storage Table service.

A `null` value property would **never** be persisted in service side regardless of performing `replace` or `merge` operation.

For example, if the previously persisted entity is `{"a":1, "b":2}` on service side, and a `merge` operation is performed with payload `{"a":null, "b":3, "c":4}`, the newly persisted entity will be `{"a":1, "b":3, "c":4}` on service side. As comparison, if the performed operation is `replace` with payload `{"a":null, "b":3, "c":4}`, the newly persisted entity will be `{"b":3, "c":4}` on service side.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct. But mostly I asked this question to prompt for an improvement to the documentation. My point is, I had to figure all of this out for myself and the documentation seems misleading.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider sending the feedback in doc page. :)

Comment: Yes, and hopefully this question helps other people until the docs are improved. I searched the docs and Stack Overflow before asking this question!

Comment: Had the same concern, thanks @DaveSexton for the question and  @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft for the clarification! Basically, entities are stripped of `null` properties then the actual operation happens.